# Using PUT method AJAX results in empty $request->all() array in Laravel 6

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, api

I have a very simple form for testing purposes, when I try to PUT the formData using $.ajax I get a empty array response but this happen only when I use PUT method, if I use POST instead of PUT method works as expected.

I'm using Laravel 6, I have a var_dump in each function:

```php
var_dump($request->all())
```

When I use PUT method I get:

```
array(0) {}
```

When I use POST method I get:

```
array(4) { ["form1"]=> string(1) "1" ["form2"]=> string(1) "2" ["form3"]=> string(1) "3" ["form4"]=> string(1) "4" }
```

I need the formData because I going to PUT image files. I was looking for another similar questions but no one solves my issue.

There are another method to perform this?

```html
<form id="formTest" type="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="form1" value="1">
    <input name="form2" value="2">
    <input name="form3" value="3">
    <input name="form4" value="4">
    <button type="submit">Accept</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#formTest').on('submit', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?echo($config->get('apiUrl'))?>movies/13',
                type: 'PUT',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: formData,
                success: function(result)
                {
                },
                error: function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using Route::put() in your routes file?

Comment: @MatMorici yes, for PUT I'm Using: Route::put('movies/{id}','MoviesController@update');  And for POST: Route::post('movies','MoviesController@add');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding these two input fields in your form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

The first one is changed the form submission method to "PUT" and the second one is including the CSRF Token to the form.

Then in your AJAX code, change the **type: 'PUT'** to **type: 'POST'**.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?echo($config->get('apiUrl'))?>movies/13',
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function(result) {},
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```